# CakePHP redirect entire page instead of div

Tags: ajax, cakephp

When I'm logging in with my CakePHP login function in the Users controller using ajax. The errors will be displayed in an Div above the login form. But when I have a successful login, I want to redirect the page to the homepage. When I'm using `$this->redirect('home');` in the Users controller, the Div will only be updated.

How can I make sure that the entire page will be reloaded? I rather fix this problem with PHP than Javascript 'cause I'm using the Writebuffer method with the JSHelper.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be solved in client side. Because client browser gets the AJAX response and puts the output inside the DIV.

Although you can embed javascript code inside the AJAX response. For example, if login is incorrect, then put a window.location javascript code inside the output. But this is not a good solution.

Return an HTTP status code within AJAX response. If for example code is 401, then redirect.

```
if (data == '401') {
  document.location.href="http://example.com";
}
```